# Fast approximations of Lyapunov exponents in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

I have $x_i$ sampled IID from $\mathcal{D}$=Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with 0 mean and diagonal covariance $H=\operatorname{diag}h$ and need to find the largest value of $\alpha$, such that the following infinite product converges to 0.

$$f(\alpha)=\underbrace{(1,1,\ldots,1)}_d.\underbrace{(I-\alpha x_1x_1')}_{d\times d}.(I-\alpha x_2x_2').(I-\alpha x_3x_3')...$$

Call this value $\alpha_c$

Using Monte-Carlo simulation below for various values of $\alpha$, I
estimate that

$$\alpha_c \in [0.269538, 0.404307]$$ for

$$h=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{100}\right)$$

**What tools in Mathematica might I use to get a more accurate estimate?**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
gaussianSampler[diag_] := 
  With[{d = Length[diag]}, 
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
    Module[{vals, diagSqrt}, diagSqrt = Sqrt[diag];
     vals = 
      diagSqrt*# & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}]]]];
SF = StringForm;
nf[x_] = NumberForm[N@x, {3, 3}];

d = 100;
h = Table[i^-1, {i, 1, d}];
ones = ConstantArray[1., d];
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
sampler = gaussianSampler[h];

spectralRadius[mat_] := Max@Eigenvalues[mat, 1];
lowerBound = 
  With[{hh = {h}\[Transpose] . {h}, H = N@DiagonalMatrix[h]}, 
   2 spectralRadius[2 H + hh . Inverse[H]]^-1];

numSteps = 1000;

XX := With[{X = sampler[1]}, X\[Transpose] . X];
f[alpha_] := Norm@Nest[(ii - alpha*XX) . # &, ones, numSteps];

alphaVals = {lowerBound*0.8, lowerBound, lowerBound*1.2};
fvals = f /@ alphaVals;
Print[SF["approx log f(alpha) after `` steps", numSteps]];
TableForm[{alphaVals, Log@fvals}\[Transpose], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"alpha", "log f(alpha)"}}]
```

We know that $[0,\alpha_c]$ gives the range of step-sizes for which [LMS filter  is stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Convergence_and_stability_in_the_mean) for observations distributed at $\mathcal{D}$.

For the special case of $h=(1,1)$, the value of $\alpha_c$ has been determined [analytically](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430781/range-of-a-such-that-w-leftarrow-w-a-x-langle-w-x-rangle-converges-almos/430790#430790) to be $\alpha_c=0.937087$. This technique doesn't generalize to more general values of $h$.

[image]

Comment: Can you reduce this to a scalar problem? Since you're summing all the elements with the vector of 1s, you may only need to consider the largest eigenvalue (if that diverges then you're lost, but if it's finite, so will the others).

Comment: For scalar problems $x_1 x_2\cdots$ converges if $E_i[\log x_i]<0$. If $x_i$ are matrices, perhaps the analogous condition is that $E_i[\log x_i]$ has only negative eigenvalues where $\log$ is matrix logarithm. I suspect this problem is equivalent in difficulty to computing top Lyapunov exponent, doubt simple scalar reduction is possible